# Web Deploy unable to validate connection

Tags: iis, web-deployment

I am trying to learn how to setup Web Deploy functionality on both sides Server and host/client computer. Created a Windows Server 2012 Web Server in Hyper-V and able to access default web page in host/client computer. On server installed Web Maintenance Service, Web Deploy 3.5 and performed all the required steps e.g. "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" and added Administrator to IIS Manager Permission for the website in IIS. I disabled Firewall totally to make it work for the first time.

On client computer I created a dummy MVC Application in Visual Studio and trying to create publish profile for this app. As soon as I hit the Validate Connection I got the option to receive and save the security certificate from server but after that in gives me following warning (snapshot):

[image]

Tried doing all the steps all over but no luck.

I am open to all feedback. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Instead of adding publish information manually, I am suppose to use publishsetting file generated in server through "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" feature of IIS. Server address ends with file name which ends with .axd